# Is there any side-effect for making python list more like R list?

Tags: python, r, list, class, built-in

```
$ lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
$ lst[[0,3]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

Python list does not support indexing with integer list.
R supports it. I am from R. So I thought,
why not make it possible?

So here's my code.

```
class list2(list):
    def __getitem__(self, x):
        if isinstance(x, __builtins__.list):
            #print(x)
            return [__builtins__.list.__getitem__(self, y) for y in x]
        else:
            return __builtins__.list.__getitem__(self,x)
            
l = list2(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
l[[2,3]]
```

It works as I expected.

My question is "can any side effect occur so that I need to take caution in using my `list2()`?"

I don't think there is since python list does not allow list in `lst[]` or `.__getitem__()` in the first place but who knows?

### UPDATES

I found one case that does not extend smoothly.

`del lst[1]` or `del lst[::2]` works fine but
`del lst[[1,3]]` does not work.

But I don't think this is a serious problem because
it does not break compatibility of existing source.

Comment: np.arrays pretty much do this already...

Comment: The side effect for any other pythonista is:  "HUH?" Whats that? You loose (or would have to recreate) the "normal" ways to generate list like:  `c = [a*2 for a in range(20)]` - I do not see any benefit - it is also 1 letter longer then normal slicing

Comment: Why are you using `__builtins__`??? As stated already, if you want R-like data structures, use `numpy` and `pandas`, don't try to shoehorn the Python built-ins to something like R.

Comment: No, you cannot change how Python source code literals work, not without changing the Python runtime/ compiler itself.

Comment: @Artner I don't get it. Why do I have to **recreate** anything similar to `c=[a*2 for a in range(20)]`? I just proposed replacing `.__getitem()__` method. Everything else is intact.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I thought so but I had a hope that someone might come up with a brilliant idea that no body ever thought of like other questions I had seen, in which someone confidently declares that it was impossible but someone else came later with a brilliant answer. ex) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word

Answer (score -1):

If your intended output is 'c' and 'd', try this:

```
import pandas as pd
lst = pd.Series( ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
lst.loc[[2,3]]
```

Pandas is sort of the "make Python work like R" library.

Comment: Of course I know pandas or numpy. Anyway if you start from a list, you need to do something like `np.array(lst)[[2,3]]` or `pd.Series(lst).loc[[2,3]]` which is quite cumbersome. And `list.__getitem__()` does nothing with list argument so it could be an extension... maybe I better propose python development team...